# How do I properly use password_verify with PDO and a salt?

Tags: php, mysql, password-protection

I'm using the [password_ compatibility](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for my password_ functions and I'm trying to protect my users with this password protecting system.

Firstly, I use the `password_hash()` function for storing a hash of the password into the db, and then, I guess I have to use the `password_verify()` function when a user logs in so I can verify if he (or she) entered the password correctly.
Actually, I'm stuck in that step... I guess I have to use a *salt* and a *hash* in order to use `password_verify()`, but I don't know exactly how to take the salt created with the `password_hash()`. I've read [the official guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) but I cannot find any help there...

This is the code I actually use with the register:

```
$connection = new PDO(/*My DB details...*/);
$sql = 'INSERT into users(username, password, mail ,sex) VALUES (:username, :password, :mail, :sex)';

$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$statement->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 15);
$statement->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
$statement->bindParam(':mail', $_POST['mail'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
$statement->bindParam(':sex', $_POST['sex'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);
$result = $statement->execute();
```

Now, I don't know exactly what code I can use for the login system... Because I guess I'd have to use the `password_verify()`, but I don't know exactly where and how to put it. This is actually the code I have for my login system without password encrypting...

```
$connection = new PDO(/*My connection info...*/);
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password';

        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

        $statement->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
        $statement->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
        $result = $statement->execute();

        if ($result) {
            $result = $statement->fetchAll();
            if (!empty($result)){
                // Other code I have...
            }
```

So, what do you recommend me to use now? I'm really lost...
Thanks!

PS: Another thing I want to add is that I think I should store every user salt in the db... Am I right? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify a password you have to **retrieve** it. Means you have to select it, not use in a condition. Once selected, it can be easily verified. Sounds logically?

For the salt you don't need to worry at all - it s already stored.

Comment: Well, but then I'd have the password as `$result[0]['password']` inside the last if. And then there I would use `password_verify($result[0]['password'])` or something like this?

Comment: Seems it's time for you to discover other fetch methods beside fetchAll

Comment: And you don't need first if either

Comment: I assume I'll have to take one of [this options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), but which of them? I don't know exactly what you mean to do... Thanks!!

Comment: Well, as you said, the salt is already stored... But where? If you have some time, [take a look at this](http://pastebin.com/Y4mSEDAY), it's how I actually have my code and I explain a few things there. It all works except the part of the `password_verify()` that outputs me as false because (I think) of the salt. You'll see and hope you can help me. Thanks!!

Comment: you are using it all right. take a habit of echoing every bloody variable in case of error. or rather var_dump-ing them.

Comment: But when I do `password_verify($_POST['password'], $result[0]['password'])` it returns me false... And assuming the first variable is the password and the second is the hash of the same password... Why does it not return true? I'm a little bit confused..

Comment: DO NOT ASSUME! **Programmer should never assume anything!** Do what I said: **take a habit of echoing every bloody variable in case of error.** First of all you have to make sure that variables contain expected values.

Comment: But I've already done this and all the variables contain my expected values! The `$_POST['password']` contains my password and the `$result[0]['password']` contains the password hash (I've checked it echoing both of them), and if I do a var_dump of the password_verify with this two variables it returns a false boolean. What else do I have to check?

Comment: save generated password into file and compare it to one you get from db. the same try with plain password.

Comment: Oh... Now I see... The password field in the db is limited to 30 characters and the password hash is 60 characters long so it didn't store all the password. Thanks a lot, you have made me see the error by myself and not telling it directly to me, and I think this is a better way to learn. Seriously, thanks a lot!